# Plot normal distribution when only mean and standar deviation exists in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, normal-distribution

First of all, this is my data:

```
x <- structure(list(FIGURE = c("4", "4", "4", "4", "XXXIIIc", "XXXIIIc", 
"XXXIIIc", "XXXVI", "XXXVI", "XXXVI", "XLIV", "XLIV", "XLIV", 
"3", "3", "88", "88", "19", "19", "19", "19", "19", "18a", "18a", 
"18a", "18b", "18c", "18c", "18c", "18c", "18c", "55", "Ensemble IX", 
"2", "25", "25", "26", "26", "29", "54", "54", "130", "130"), 
    media_fecha = c(16382.5, 14759, 13776, 15941, 18189.5, 17546.5, 
    17422, 18084, 16898.5, 17987, 16422.5, 15729.5, 17615.5, 
    16016, 15864.5, 14643, 14132, 17146.5, 16619.5, 16424, 16317, 
    16328.5, 16317, 15679, 14834.5, 15467, 13197.5, 12691.5, 
    12683.5, 12384, 14545, 16053.5, 16669.5, 15234.5, 17036.5, 
    16608, 17428, 17439.5, 26785.5, 16813, 16651.5, 15432, 14655
    ), sd_fecha = c(266.25, 235.5, 131.5, 327.5, 210.25, 267.75, 
    267, 262, 239.25, 304, 283.75, 189.75, 266.75, 174, 294.75, 
    278.5, 331, 266.75, 204.75, 215.5, 196, 285.25, 196, 288.5, 
    250.25, 277, 63.75, 101.75, 100.75, 168, 337.5, 136.25, 212.75, 
    183.25, 199.25, 206.5, 193, 264.75, 312.25, 235.5, 299.25, 
    238.5, 312.5)), row.names = c(NA, -43L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This dataset is composed of 3 columns:

- `FIGURE`: categorical variable
- `media_fecha`: mean value for that element/row of the dataset.
- `sd_fecha`: standard deviation for that element/row of the dataset.

The category `XLIV` in `FIGURE` is composed of three rows or elements.

I am interested in plotting this by using `ggplot2`.

- For example, illustrate three normal distributions of `XLIV` by using their corresponding means and deviations. And also, highlight the overlapping area.

How could I do it?

### UPDATE

I would like to give a color to the overlapping area between all the density functions taking into account their corresponding 2 sigma limit. Something similar to this example of XXXIIIc:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group your data row-wise, summarize with 100 x and y values from, say, 4 sd below to 4 sd above the means, then plot with plain old `geom_line`.

If you want to highlight the areas where all the curves overlap (within 2 sd of each mean), you can find the x values that lie within that range for all curves, then mark the highest y values where this is true for filling.

We can wrap all this in a function for ease of use and consistency:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_norms <- function(data, fig, ...) {
  x %>%
    filter(FIGURE == fig) %>%
    mutate(min_range = min(media_fecha - 4 * sd_fecha),
           max_range = max(media_fecha + 4 * sd_fecha)) %>%
    mutate(group = row_number()) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    summarise(x = seq(min_range, max_range, length.out = 500),
              y = dnorm(x, media_fecha, sd_fecha),
              is_2d = x > media_fecha - 2 * sd_fecha & 
                      x < media_fecha + 2 * sd_fecha,
              FIGURE = FIGURE, group = group) %>%
    group_by(x) %>%
    mutate(fill_me = all(is_2d) & rank(y) == max(rank(y))) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
    geom_area(data = . %>% filter(fill_me), ..., position = 'identity') +
    geom_line(aes(group = group)) +
    ggtitle(paste("Normal distributions, figure", fig)) +
    theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
}
```

So now you can do:

```r
plot_norms(x, "19", fill = 'lightblue', alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

```r
plot_norms(x, "XXXIIIc", fill = 'red', alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @allan-cameron, I was able to replicate these figures. Another thing I asked is if it is possible to put a color in the background of the overlapping area between all the density plots. It is true that the previous two examples don't have any overlapped area between the density plots. However, when you use the figure 19 or XXXIIIc there are areas in common. Thanks